# Is it possible to make http call using InternetExplorer.Application instead of MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP

Tags: vba

MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP is usually used in VBA to make web service calls.  However, in my macro, a call using MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP will not have the right cookies set.  If I use InternetExplorer.Application object instead and open an invisible browser like so:

```
myIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    .Visible = False
    .Navigate "http://someserver/resources/postrequest"
```

Is it possible to get xml response from myIE object?  If so, how?  Also my request needs to be a POST instead of GET, so the above code will probably not work either.

Comment: Is it a google search you are looking for or presumably something more complex? You can login to sites using XMLHTTp, so I'm unclear why you think the cookies will be an issue

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  It has nothing to do with google and that's just a stand-in for an url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out that you can get the cookie from InternetExplorer.Application and use it for the subsequent web request calls.
[How can I access cookie from InternetExplorer.Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690947/how-can-i-access-cookie-from-internetexplorer-application)